# Using jquery to initialise a bootstrap progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap progress bar, which is set to zero

```
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" id="p1"
    role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0"
    aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:0%">
```

I use the following jquery code to initialise the progress bar

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "myurl.php",
        data: data
    }).done(function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
    var pid = msg.pid;
    var colour = msg.colour;
    var comp = msg.comp;
    console.log('pid = ' + pid);
    console.log('colour = ' + colour);
    document.getElementById(pid).style.width = comp;
    document.getElementById(pid).innerHTML = comp + '% Complete';   
    document.getElementById(pid).classList.add(colour); 
    });
```

I am getting valid data from the ajax request,

```
Object {pid: "p1", comp: 7, colour: "progress-bar-success"}
```

But, the progress bar does not update. If I initialise the bar in the html to begin at 1%, it does work using the above code. Is there a way to get this initialised using jquery?

Comment: did you miss `%` while adding width? or is it a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add "%" when you set the width of the progress bar;

```
document.getElementById(pid).style.width = comp + "%";
```

Jquery Solution

```
$("#"+pid ).css('width', comp + "%");
```